# custom directive not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, custom-directive

I'm trying to create a directive for redacted/private information.
If certain information is not provided a black box should be shown (as if the content was there but made invisible with a black box)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit } from 
'@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appRedactedContent]'
})
export class RedactedContentDirective implements OnInit {
min = 75;
max = 150;
width = this.randomIntFromInterval(this.min, this.max);
constructor(private el: ElementRef,
          private renderer: Renderer) {
          }
ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer.setElementStyle(
        this.el.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue !important');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'width', 
                                      this.width.toString());
  }

randomIntFromInterval(min: number, max: number): number {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
}
```

html

```
<a appRedactedContent></a>
```

I can see the style being added when I open my developer tools but the a-tag I can't see a blue box in my browser

Comment: Remove `!important` and add `px` to width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  tag as a default display to inline, you cant enforce is width nor is height.

As your a tag do not have a content it as a width of 0 and then you cant see it

if you want to enforce the width, you have to set its display to inline-block

[ref to HTML specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)